# Get span content using rvest

Tags: html, r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a set of web pages with `rvest` package. It works when getting the content of the web pages, but I can't get create time for the first floor, which is **2017-08-17 01:47** for this web page.

```
url <- read_html("http://tieba.baidu.com/p/5275787419", encoding = "UTF-8")
# This works
contents <- url %>% html_nodes(".d_post_content_firstfloor .clearfix") %>% html_text()
# This doesn't work
create_time <- url %>% html_nodes(".d_post_content_firstfloor li+ li span") %>% html_text()
create_time
character(0)
```

I want to get the time of first floor on the web but I don't know how to access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this could be

```
create_time<- url %>% html_nodes(xpath= '//*[@id="j_p_postlist"]/div[1]') %>% xml_attr("data-field")
gsub(".*date\\\":\\\"(.*)\\\",\\\"vote_crypt.*","\\1",create_time)
```

Output is:

```
[1] "2017-08-17 01:47"
```

Hope this helps!